# Recover local files after git switch?

Tags: git

I wanted to switch branches in git, and I had about 3 currently untracked files. When I switched branches, those files got overwritten/deleted locally. Is there any way I can recover those files?

I placed the local files in a stash using git stash, but when I tried to pop the stash, those files did not come back. Is there anything I can do to recover those files? I did not commit those files yet.

Comment: `git stash`  will not  stash the untracked file.

Comment: `git checkout` will not modify the untracked file too

Comment: Did you `git clean` at some point in the process?

Comment: @LF00 [`git stash push --include-untracked`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt---include-untracked).

Comment: You can look at the stash entry with `git stash show --name-status`. If the files are not in there, they are gone.